# Sublists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Pandas DataFrame, one of the columns of which looks like this:

```
0              {u'funny': 2, u'useful': 0, u'cool': 0}
1        {u'funny': 370, u'useful': 487, u'cool': 296}
2             {u'funny': 2, u'useful': 17, u'cool': 1}
3     {u'funny': 1233, u'useful': 2452, u'cool': 1875}
4              {u'funny': 4, u'useful': 7, u'cool': 2}
5        {u'funny': 408, u'useful': 819, u'cool': 557}
6        {u'funny': 321, u'useful': 673, u'cool': 430}
7           NaN
8              {u'funny': 0, u'useful': 8, u'cool': 0}
```

I want to break this column out into separate columns, without iterating over all of the rows explicitly (there are a lot, plus it's bad practice).

`DataFrame.ThisColumn[1]["funny"]` returns 2, but `DataFrame.ThisColumn[:]["funny"]` doesn't work....

How can I break this into separate columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just apply the Series constructor to that column:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                                               dics
0           {u'funny': 2, u'useful': 0, u'cool': 0}
1     {u'funny': 370, u'useful': 487, u'cool': 296}
2          {u'funny': 2, u'useful': 17, u'cool': 1}
3  {u'funny': 1233, u'useful': 2452, u'cool': 1875}
4           {u'funny': 4, u'useful': 7, u'cool': 2}
5     {u'funny': 408, u'useful': 819, u'cool': 557}
6     {u'funny': 321, u'useful': 673, u'cool': 430}
7           {u'funny': 0, u'useful': 8, u'cool': 0}

In [12]: df['dics'].apply(pd.Series)
Out[12]:
   cool  funny  useful
0     0      2       0
1   296    370     487
2     1      2      17
3  1875   1233    2452
4     2      4       7
5   557    408     819
6   430    321     673
7     0      0       8
```

**However**, I think it's almost certainly best to split these when constructing your DataFrame, rather than once they are already in the DataFrame.

Comment: @N.McA. well, however you are getting your data, best to try and do it first! :)

Comment: It's a JSON that's already formatted like this, and I' not in charge of scraping it so I'm not sure I can

Comment: @N.McA. Perhaps worth looking at [pandasjson](https://github.com/pydata/pandasjson) (there's a [pr to get in main pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3583) so I guess Wes thinks it's pretty stable).

Comment: Cheers, I will. Note that I edited my question to include an NA... Do you know how best to handle that?

Comment: Hmmm, a simple is to just apply something like `make_series = lambda x: pd.Series(x) if x == nan else x`, there's probably a more efficient way though.